# how to write xpath for matching multiple attributes with value specific values

Tags: c#-4.0

I am writing this code

```
("//series/@*[Place='" + place + "'] and [Date='"+date+"']")
```

My XML is as follows:

```
<series>
<Note roll="2" place="OFFICE" Date="12/6/2014 12:00:00 AM">
<value>abc</value>
</Note>
<Note roll="2" place="bank" Date="11/6/2014 12:00:00 AM">
</Note>
<value>abc</value>
</series>
```

I want to find all nodes that have value of `place= office` and `date =12/6/2014` ,
but it's not giving the correct output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The XML isn't valid. You have multiple root elements, and the `Note` elements are not terminated.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa . But still i am not getting the right output after terminating the note element.

Comment: With a correct XML it's possible to test it out against different XPath expressions.

Comment: @Guffa Can you give me the code(Xpath) for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `and` operator, just place the conditions after each other.

Instead of selecting attributes with a specific value (`@*[...]`) you should select nodes with specific attribute values (`*[@...]`).

Example:

```
/series/*[@place='bank'][@Date='11/6/2014 12:00:00 AM']
```

So in the code that would be:

```
("/series/*[@place='" + place + "'][@Date='" + date + "']")
```

Working example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<series><Note roll=\"2\" place=\"OFFICE\" Date=\"12/6/2014 12:00:00 AM\"><value>abc</value></Note><Note roll=\"2\" place=\"bank\" Date=\"11/6/2014 12:00:00 AM\"></Note><value>abc</value></series>");

string place = "bank";
string date = "11/6/2014 12:00:00 AM";

XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/series/*[@place='" + place + "'][@Date='" + date + "']");
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // outputs 1
```

Comment: thank u buddy but this is not working in my case :-)

Comment: @zombie: It's working perfectly when I test it with the XML that you showed. If it doesn't work in your case, then there is something that you are not showing.

Comment: It should be "//series[@place='" + place + "']|//series[@Date='" + date + "']"..Finally the problem is solved..thanx for ur support buddy.:-)

Comment: @zombie: That will get you items that match the place *or* the date, not the place *and* the date.

Comment: u r ryt,The code is calculating all the values and is  not checking the condition